# How to get all elements with a class within wait

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping the xbox website with selenium but I encountered a problem when extracting someone's followers and friends: both elements have the same class, with no other property setting them apart, so I need to find all elements with that class and append them to a list and get the first, second value.  I just need to know how to find all elements with a class whilst using wait until as seen below

```py
followers = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item-value-data"))).text
#this currently only gets the first element
```

I am aware of how to do this without wait; just putting `elements`, but I couldn't find anything regarding using this in wait.

Comment: Can you please provide a link of wesbite you want to scrape / image of element / html code?

Comment: Can you share HTML in text format here ?

Comment: This should work : https://ibb.co/m4Fvb1F

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriverWait` waits until at least 1 element matching the passed condition is found.
There is no expected condition supported by Selenium with Python to wait for predefined amount of elements matching or something like this.
What you can do is to put a small sleep after the wait to make the page fully loaded and then get the list of desired elements.
Like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item-value-data")))
time.sleep(1)
followers = []
followers_els = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".item-value-data")
for el in followers_els:
    followers.append(el.text)
```

Comment: Thank you this looks like it should work.  I will try it when I am back home and mark it as correct

Comment: Is there no way to work with presence_of_all_elements_located?

Comment: It doesn't actually validates presence of all elements matching the passed locator. Once it finds at least one match - it returns a list of matching elements. The only difference is that `presence_of_element_located` returns web element object while `presence_of_all_elements_located` retuns a list of web elements.

Comment: In Java we have `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(element, expectedElementsAmount));` and `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(element, expectedElementsAmount));` . Selenium in Python doesn't support such methods.